# Como gerenciar ambientes de homologação e produção com Team Services?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Estou em um projeto de ASP.Net C# que está começando agora, mas eu venho do *ASP Clássico*, onde as coisas são bem diferentes.

Neste novo projeto precisamos fazer a criação e gestão de ambientes de homologação e produção, onde as alterações devem ir para o ambiente de homologação, testadas por outra equipe, e após aprovadas, vão para o servidor de produção.

A forma como fazíamos isso no *ASP Clássico* era simplesmente ter dois domínios, com FTP distintos, e após aprovado no ambiente de homologação, nós copiávamos os arquivos de um FTP para o outro, para que fique disponível na produção.

No .Net fui introduzido ao *Team Services*, mas, confesso que ainda não caiu bem a ficha de como ele funciona e se ele consegue me ajudar neste problema aparentemente simples.

Minha pergunta é: Como funciona o Team Services e como ele poderia me ajudar neste controle de versões e ambientes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[A melhor introdução é esta aqui](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs.aspx).

Em projetos que usam Git, uma boa prática que está se tornando comum é não realizar *commits* e *pushes* no *branch* `master`: este *branch* normalmente é utilizado para a integração contínua, ou seja, cada vez que código novo é mandado ou juntado (*merged*) em master, há um recurso que pode ser ativado para que o projeto seja testado e publicado sozinho.

Para as equipes, devem ser criados outros *branches* que representem ou fluxos de trabalho (*dev*, *refactoring*, *layout*, etc.) ou novas funcionalidades ("nome-do-recurso-novo1", "antigo-recurso-refatorado2", etc.). Quando as funcionalidades são concluídas, faz-se o *merge* para master e, dependendo da configuração, o serviço de integração continua sobe o projeto para uma instância de testes ou até mesmo a produção.

[O TFS tem o mesmo recurso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee308011(v=vs.100).aspx).

Além disso, há uma série de ferramentas oferecidas que são inerentes ao esforço de desenvolvimento de um projeto, como Backlog, ferramentas de produtividade e integração com outros serviços em nuvem.

Com isso, a ideia de usar FTP é simplesmente defasada. Por exemplo, num projeto ASP.NET MVC com Entity Framework, a atualização do banco é feita automaticamente por um processo chamado [Web Deploy](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis), que também tem a função de publicar o código no servidor de aplicação.

Comment: Já usei (Git e TSF) se fosse para escolher ficaria com o GIT.

Comment: @MarconcílioSouza Somos dois.

Comment: Acho que sou o único que acha o **TFS** melhor que o GIT. Se for utilizar o Team Services por completo então...

Comment: Não tem a ver com a pergunta mas para os comentários. Agora a MS chama de **TFVC**.

Comment: @Randrade O problema do TFS são os *merges*, jovem. Eu também gostava, até que tive que trabalhar com *separated features*.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Eu nunca tive problema com ele. Tenho problemas com O VS + Git nessa questão, mas isso é por causa do VS e não do GIT.

Comment: Desculpe por ser tão cru em .Net, mas, ainda estou com dúvida. Digamos que meu servidor de produção esteja em producao.com.br, e as alterações precisam ficar publicadas para análise antes de ir pra produção...o TFS (ou Git) faria algo como producao.com.br:5506, ou eu teria que criar um desenvolvimento.com.br e apontar para os arquivos não homologados? 
Estou realmente começando em .Net, por isso estou com essas dúvidas.

Comment: Eu faria um *branch* para o producao.com.br e outro para desenvolvimento.com.br, ambos com integração contínua. Quando uma etapa do desenvolvimento termina, você faz uma operação de *merge* para o *branch* do desenvolvimento. O código sobe sozinho. Você testa. Estando tudo ok, você faz outro *merge*, desta vez do *branch* de desenvolvimento para o *branch* de produção.

Comment: Entendi...ficou bem claro agora. Muito obrigado @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 3):

Completando a resposta do Cigano Morrison,

Para gerenciar e deploy de vários ambiente você pode usar o Release Management
https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/release-management/

Aqui trabalhamos como o Cigano comentou, temos um branch master onde temos uma Build Definition com uma trigger apontando para este branch master. Todo checkin que é feito neste branch é o gatilho para enfileirar uma build. Ao concluir toda build a equipe recebe uma notificação por email.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E temos também um Release Definition onde a trigger é justamente nossa Build Definition. A cada build completada com sucesso é disparada nossa release que é bem simples, apenas faz uma publicação da aplicação no servidor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém com o Release management você pode configurar muito mais detalhes como a publicação em diversos ambientes, que aguardam a aprovação e ao serem aprovados são publicados no próximo ambiente. Por exemplo, publicar em um ambiente de homologação, ao ser aprovado para um ambiente de pre-produção, ao ser aprovado, publicar em produção.

Pode também executar diversos processos como testes ou mesmo rodar comandos locais nos servidores para ajustes de ambiente.